# Visual Studio 2013 stops working after installation of Code Contracts

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, code-contracts

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 on my dev machine and was missing Code Contracts support afterwards (had it installed previously), so I reinstalled Code Contracts. Immediately thereafter, Visual Studio refused to start up with the error message "A problem occurred when loading the Microsoft Visual Menu....", as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506703/problems-occurred-when-loading-the-microsoft-visual-menu).

I tried to do as advised in the message in every possible way I can think of, but none of them worked.

So I reinstalled Visual Studio 2013 and got the following behaviour:

VS does launch up correctly for exactly **one single time**, right after the reinstall. Any subsequent lauch fails with the error message described above. I verified this by reinstalling VS a second time and got the same result.

I then uninstalled Code Contracts, reinstalled VS again and still got the same. After completely wiping my system of .net framework 4.5.1 and reinstalling VS again, I was finally rid of this message.

So I braced myself, launched up the Code Contracts installer and guess it? Same procedure as every year: One single correct VS launch, all subsequents with error, again!

I did the same setup on two other machines, neither of which had any problems.

What can I try next (short of wiping my whole machine)?

Comment: Do you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: The n'th Visual Studio 2013 repair installation finally got things working for me. But by this time I had gotten so frantic that it is hard to say, in retrospect, which exact steps I have taken. My Visual Studio installation was, however, still somewhat broken: After I installed Visual Studio 2015 things went completely haywire, to the point where I had to (finally) wipe my box. Now I have a fresh Win10 installation with VS2013 , VS2015 and even CodeContracts on it. All working with no problems whatsoever...